# scroll anchoring on non-chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

Hi there, I'm trying to implement an infinite-scrolling blog, and have the functionality working in terms of loading and rendering. However, I'm getting jumpy performance on non-chrome browsers due to content being dynamically rendered as the user scrolls.

I found that it works perfectly in chrome due to the scroll anchoring functionality (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/scroll-anchoring), but other browsers like safari or firefox not so much. Does anyone know how to go about emulating the scroll anchoring functionality so that the infinite scroll functionality works on all major browsers?

I really appreciate any thoughts or suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: Firefox 66 supports it now